# Determine dynamic window width: efficient rolling count of values which satisfy a condition

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a data.frame with two columns `a` and `b`, where `a` is sorted. I want to get the rolling average of `b`, where the window is the range `a - 5` to `a` (i.e. from the current value of `a` to wherever `a - 5` is).

Performing the rolling average with different window widths is trivial using `data.table::frollmean()` (`adaptive = TRUE`; "each single observation has own corresponding rolling window width"), so the only problem is calculating those window widths.

So, given the following data.frame, how can I determine the window size for each mean?

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- data.frame(
    a = sort(runif(10, 0, 10)),
    b = 1:10
)
x
#>           a  b
#> 1  1.346666  1
#> 2  2.861395  2
#> 3  5.190959  3
#> 4  6.417455  4
#> 5  6.569923  5
#> 6  7.050648  6
#> 7  7.365883  7
#> 8  8.304476  8
#> 9  9.148060  9
#> 10 9.370754 10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If I were to put the window size as a new column `n`, I'd expect the result to be

```r
#>           a  b n
#> 1  1.346666  1 1
#> 2  2.861395  2 2
#> 3  5.190959  3 3
#> 4  6.417455  4 3
#> 5  6.569923  5 4
#> 6  7.050648  6 5
#> 7  7.365883  7 6
#> 8  8.304476  8 6
#> 9  9.148060  9 7
#> 10 9.370754 10 8
```

So, for example, there are two values between `a[2] = 2.86` and `2.86 - 5` (including itself), and there are six values between `a[8] = 8.30` and `8.30 - 5`.

I've managed to do this using `outer`:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(magrittr)
    library(data.table)
})

f <- function(x, y) {
    return(y %between% list(x - 5, x))
}

outer(x$a, x$a, f) %>% rowSums()
#>  [1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7 8
```

However, my real case has easily 5000 rows, and this method gets quite slow (takes around 10 seconds). One problem I see is that it compares every value of `a` to every other value of `a`, so has to perform some 25,000,000 comparisons. However, I know `a` is sorted, so if we find a stretch of `TRUE` results in the comparison and then a `FALSE`, we know all subsequent results for the current value of `a` will also be `FALSE` (that would mean we were in the allowable range and then moved past the highest allowable value of `a`, so everything else will also be rejected).

So, is there a better, faster way of doing this?

Comment: Or `seq_along(x$a) - findInterval(x$a - 5, x$a)`

Comment: @Henrik that second solution is very elegant, and instantaneous on my 5000-row case. Feel free to add that as an answer for an upvote and almost certainly a checkmark (I like to wait a day or two for more answers).

Comment: @chinsoon12 no, `a` is unique and monotonically increasing.

Comment: @chinsoon12 the former `a-5 <= x <= a`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it seems that you will load `data.table` anyway (for `frollmean`), you may coerce your `data.frame` to `data.table`, and add the new column by reference.

`findInterval` is used to find the index of each subtracted value among the original values. This index is then subtracted from the original index, obtained by `.I` or `seq_along`, to get the window size.

```
setDT(x)
x[ , n := .I - findInterval(a - 5, a)]

# x
#            a  b n
#  1: 1.346666  1 1
#  2: 2.861395  2 2
#  3: 5.190959  3 3
#  4: 6.417455  4 3
#  5: 6.569923  5 4
#  6: 7.050648  6 5
#  7: 7.365883  7 6
#  8: 8.304476  8 6
#  9: 9.148060  9 7
# 10: 9.370754 10 8
```

---

Similar with `base`:

```
x$n = seq_along(x$a) - findInterval(x$a - 5, x$a)
```

Comment: I think OP needs data.table for adaptive argument in frollmean in the first place

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative approach which *aggregates in a non-equi self join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, low := a - 5][
  , n := x[x, on = .(a >= low , a <= a), by = .EACHI, .N]$N][
      , low := NULL][]
```

> ```
>            a  b n
>  1: 1.346666  1 1
>  2: 2.861395  2 2
>  3: 5.190959  3 3
>  4: 6.417455  4 3
>  5: 6.569923  5 4
>  6: 7.050648  6 5
>  7: 7.365883  7 6
>  8: 8.304476  8 6
>  9: 9.148060  9 7
> 10: 9.370754 10 8
> ```

But the OP is aiming at *computing a rolling mean with a variable window size*.

So, why stop here and call `frollmean()` when we can have it in one go?:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, low := a - 5][
  , roll.mean := x[x, on = .(a >= low , a <= a), by = .EACHI, mean(b)]$V1][
    , low := NULL][]
```

> ```
>            a  b roll.mean
>  1: 1.346666  1       1.0
>  2: 2.861395  2       1.5
>  3: 5.190959  3       2.0
>  4: 6.417455  4       3.0
>  5: 6.569923  5       3.5
>  6: 7.050648  6       4.0
>  7: 7.365883  7       4.5
>  8: 8.304476  8       5.5
>  9: 9.148060  9       6.0
> 10: 9.370754 10       6.5
> ```

#### Benchmark

As the OP is concerned about the performance for his production use case here is a benchmark which varies the number of rows as well as the size of the window:

```
library(bench)
library(ggplot2)

bm <- press(
  n = 10^(c(2, 3, 4)),
  window_size = c(5, 15, 50),
  {
    set.seed(42)
    x0 <- data.table(
      a = sort(runif(n, 0, n)),
      b = seq(n)
    )
    mark(
      findInterval = {
        x <- copy(x0)
        x[, roll.mean := frollmean(b, .I - findInterval(a - window_size, a), adaptive = TRUE)]
      },
      non_equi_join = {
        x <- copy(x0)
        x[, low := a - window_size][
          , roll.mean := x[x, on = .(a >= low , a <= a), by = .EACHI, mean(b)]$V1][
            , low := NULL]
      }
    )
  }
)

autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Apparently,

- the combination of [Henrik's `findInterval()` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721224/3817004) with the adaptive `frollmean()` always is more than a magnitude faster than the *non-equi join* approach
- window size seems to have no impact on performance.

Comment: Hi @Uwe. Before my ["Or comment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718434/efficient-rolling-count-of-vector-elements-which-satisfy-a-condition?noredirect=1#comment110914152_62718434) I was actually suggesting non-equi. I suspected it could be slower than `findInterval` though, but didn't quantify it. Therefore it was nice to see your (as always) thorough answer (+1). Cheers

Comment: Thank you, @Henrik. BTW: I also benchmarked a *left join with complex condition* using `sqldf()` but I did not post the results because the performance was so poor (2 magnitudes slower than *non-equi join* for `n = 10000`).

Comment: Great to see that adaptive arg is useful. Note that adaptive uses multiple threads even for a single column/window input, so number of threads in machine may affect timings.